# Angular2 'The selector "playlist" did not match any elements'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've followed a tutorial on angular2, I've created a component that is called 'playlist' and when I run my website I get the following error in the development console:

> EXCEPTION: The selector "playlist" did not match any elements
>   angular2.dev.js:23887 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): The selector "playlist" did not match any elements
>   angular2-polyfills.js:469 Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "playlist" did not match any elements ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "The selector "playlist" did not match any elements", stack: "Error: The selector "playlist" did not match any e…es/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:227:44)"}consoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:469drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:498ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
>   angular2-polyfills.js:471 Error: Uncaught (in promise): The selector "playlist" did not match any elements(…)consoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:471drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:498ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
>   angular2-polyfills.js:469 Unhandled Promise rejection: The selector "playlist" did not match any elements ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "The selector "playlist" did not match any elements", stack: "Error: The selector "playlist" did not match any e…es/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:227:44)"}consoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:469drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:498ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
>   angular2-polyfills.js:471 Error: Uncaught (in promise): The selector "playlist" did not match any elements(…)

My Code:

app component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Settings} from './config';
import {Video} from './video';
import {PlaylistComponent} from './playlist.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/app.component.html',
    directives: [PlaylistComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = Settings.MAIN_HEADING;
    videos: Array<Video>;

    constructor() {
        this.videos = [
            new Video(0, 'Video No1', 'f8qBeaGe2S4', 'First video ever!'),
            new Video(1, 'Video No2', 'bKWDKmHvF78', 'Second video :D')
        ]
    }

}
```

app html:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<playlist [videos]="videos"></playlist>
```

playlist component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'playlist',
    templateUrl: 'app/ts/playlist.component.html',
    inputs: ['videos']
})

export class PlaylistComponent {}
```

playlist html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#v of vidoes">
            <td>{{ v.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ v.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ v.desc }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: im afraid to ask, but what version of angular2 are you using...?

Comment: I'm using angular 2.0.0-beta.13

Comment: I doubt you'll find support here for such an old version. A lot has changed in angular2 the past year..

Comment: I was following a tutorial online and the package.json had this version..

Comment: Oh dear. Well, just go to [angular.io](https://angular.io). All the information you need is there

Comment: have you declared PlaylistComponent  in @NgModule() ?